# Accessing function as attribute in a Python class

Tags: python, django, metaprogramming

I'm in a situation where it would be extremely useful (though not strictly necessary) to access a class' instancemethod as an attribute. (it's for an API that uses getattr to set some return values for a dictionary and I don't want to mess the neat little thing up)

I remember reading something about an `@attribute` decorator, but I can't find one (either in Python or Django)

TL;DR:

How do I make this:

```
class foo:
    bar = "bar"
    def baz(self):
        return "baz"
```

do this:

```
>>> f = foo()
>>> f.baz
"baz"
```

(edit for clarity) instead of this:

```
>>> f = foo()
>>> f.baz
<bound method foo.baz of <__builtin__.foo instance at 0x...>>
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use the [`@property`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) decorator.

```
class foo(object):
    bar = "bar"
    @property
    def baz(self):
        return "baz"
```

Comment: this returns `<property at 0x121101450>` for me

Comment: That's not working.

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at the decorator form of [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property).

```
@property
def baz(self):
  return "baz"
```